# Выбрать значения по одной колонке MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Как из БД сделать выборку по одной колонке с конкретным указанием значений.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `emails` 
 WHERE (email='test@mail.ru' and email='test2@gmail.com')
```

`Where in` не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `emails` 
WHERE email='test@mail.ru' OR email='test2@gmail.com';
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это работает так как и where in

Comment: @user575240 A как вы хотите? Одно поле не может быть равно двум значениям одновременно (как указано в вопросе)

Comment: А как это сделать правильно?

Comment: У меня есть фильтра типа характеристики, там есть product_id , feature_id вот мне нужно выбрать так что бы feature_id было несколько значений но через and потому как когда применяю or where in то продукт выводит если совпадет хотя бы одна характеристика, а нужно что бы когда выбираешь вторую но ее нет у продукта тогда его не показывать

Comment: Например вот так prod_id = 3 and fet_id where in [3,4,5] сработает если найдет хоть одно из значений, а мне нужно если нет хотя бы 4 то уже не показывать

Comment: Вообщем нужно что то типа where in 3 and 4 and 5

Comment: В таблице должны быть записи с prod_id =3  и с каждым из трех feature_id?

Comment: нет я к примеру говорю
есть 
prod_id = 3 fet = 1
prod_id = 3 fet = 2
prod_id = 3 fet = 3
Делаю выборку where prod_id = 3 and fet = 1 and fet = 2

Comment: Ну, это `... where prod_id=3 and (fet=1 or fet=2);`,  скобки обязательно нужны

Comment: http://prntscr.com/msqpep
SELECT * FROM `prods` WHERE `prod_id` = 3 and (`fet_id` = 1 or `fet_id` = 5)
Выведет одно значение в любом случае, а нужно что бы не выводил

Comment: Можете сделать `... where prod_id=3 and (fet=1 or fet=2)` а потом `group by` и `count` чтоб узнать, что строк с `prod_id=3 ` выбралось именно две

Answer (score 0):

Вот как оно на самом деле, сложновато но результат достигнут
SELECT res.* FROM (SELECT 2 as total,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `prods` as t1 WHERE t1.`fet_id` = 1 OR t1.`fet_id` = 5) as current,
t2.*
FROM `prods` as t2 WHERE t2.`fet_id` in (1,5)) as res WHERE res.total = res.current

Answer (score 0):

Недавно решал такую задачу. Можно сделать на подзапросах.
Суть такова каждый новый фильтр это новый подзапрос (например увеличиваем префикс по итерации) который обязательно экранируется скобками. Если в одном фильтре несколько вариантов пишем через "OR"
Затем объединяем все подзапросы с помощью "AND" и берем опять все в скобки.

Мой пример для joomla

```
// Dynamic filters
    $dynamicFilters = $this->getState('filter.dynamic_filters');
    if ( !empty( $dynamicFilters ) )
    {
        foreach($dynamicFilters as $dfKey => $dfVal){

            $dfVal = explode('-', $dfVal);

            $query->leftJoin( '#__product_attr as atrt'.$dfKey.' ON atrt'.$dfKey.'.prodid = p.id' );

            for($i = 0; $i < count($dfVal); ++$i){
                if( $i == 0 ){
                    $tmp = 'atrt'.$dfKey.'.val = ' . (int)$dfVal[$i];
                } else {
                    $tmp = $tmp . ' OR atrt'.$dfKey.'.val = ' . (int)$dfVal[$i];
                }
            }

            if (isset($tmpDF)){
                $tmpDF = $tmpDF . ' AND ' . '(' . $tmp . ')';
            } else {
                $tmpDF = '(' . $tmp  . ')';
            }

        }
        $query->where('('.$tmpDF.')');
    }
```

Comment: казалось бы: какое отношение php вообще и joomla в частности имеют к недопониманию автором вопроса синтаксиса языка sql? вы, видимо, не на этот вопрос хотели ответить.